# Cronjob concurrencyPolicy doesn't work as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cron

EKS 1.23

Following K8S [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#concurrency-policy) I added `concurrencyPolicy: Forbid` to my CronJob manifest but I can still see simultaneous runnings of the cronJob when I trigger it manually (didn't want to wait for the cron schedule time).

I expected the cronJob to create a new Job only after the previous Job has finished.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-cron
spec:
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  schedule: {{ .Values.cronSchedule | quote }}
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 0
      template:
        spec:
          .
          .
          .
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#concurrency-policy)

The `spec.concurrencyPolicy` field is also optional. It specifies how to treat concurrent executions of a job that is created by this CronJob.

**Forbid**: The CronJob does not allow concurrent runs; if it is time for a new job run and the previous job run hasn't finished yet, the CronJob skips the new job run

Note that concurrency policy only applies to the jobs created by the same cron job. If there are multiple CronJobs, their respective jobs are always allowed to run concurrently.

**This is the expected behavior. Manually created jobs are not affected by concurrencyPolicy.**